# Back button issues in Ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my app, after login, when I'm getting into any page from tabs menu, I couldn't able to see back button despite using ion-nav-back-button. For this I've managed by using ion-button manually with this function ng-click="$ionicGoBack()". But the problem is, I can't get responsive arrow button in Android and iOS as a normal back-button works. Any possible ways for it?`

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
 <button ng-click="$ionicGoBack()" class="button back-button buttons button-clear">
      <i class="icon ion-android-arrow-back"></i>
    </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try this  `<ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>` ..? see the pen http://codepen.io/edisonpappi/pen/QvywLg

Comment: Yes I tried it already. It is working for some pages. For example, From my login page, I'm logging in to the Dashboard, and from dashboard when I'm going to Recharge page, ion-nav-back-button is not working. But when I give next, I can able to see the back button using the same ion-nav-back-button. That is why I preferred the above case but now I'm having the arrow problem